# time part of a script (running time)

Tags: linux, bash, time, milliseconds, seconds

With the `time script.sh` you will get the time it took to run a script, BUT if you want to time a part of the script?

let's say I want to test how long a loop takes, I could use the **$SECONDS** function, but is there any timer that counts milliseconds?

for example in the middle of a long code:

```
    timerstart
    until [[ $loop -eq 10000 ]]; do
     ((++loop))

    echo "annoying"
    done
    timerstop
```

and then in the end of the script, I just add `echo $timerresult` , and it will display how many milliseconds it took to run only the selected code, and not the rest of the script

I'm looking for this solution so I can test parts of scripts for "slowness"..
is this possible to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bash 5.0 and later, you can use [`$EPOCHREALTIME`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-EPOCHREALTIME):

> [...] it expands to the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch as a floating point value with micro-second granularity [...]

```sh
start=$EPOCHREALTIME
for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do
    echo "annoying"
done
stop=$EPOCHREALTIME

elapsed=$(bc -l <<< "$stop - $start")
```

Comment: There was many good suggestion, but I think yours fitted my needs best, because with this you can time several functions in a script ( with several start/endpoints and se the results afterwards, so by implanting your idea and starting the script with `time script.sh` I would get both a full time and times of different loops and stuffs!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
date '+%s.%N'
```

to get the current time with nanosecond precision.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date '+%s.%N')
until [[ $loop -eq 10000 ]]; do
    ((++loop))
    
    echo "annoying"
done
stop=$(date '+%s.%N')
bc <<< $stop-$start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` in the script for individual parts too, e.g. to time the loop:

```
time until [[ $loop -eq 10000 ]]; do
 ((++loop))

 echo "annoying"
done
```

or with a brace group to time a group of commands:

```
time {
 until [[ $loop -eq 10000 ]]; do
  ((++loop))
 done

 echo "Other commands here that are also timed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop in a function.

```
#!/bin/bash
myloop() {
    loop=1
    until [[ $loop -eq 10000 ]]; do
       ((++loop))
       echo "annoying"
    done
}

time myloop
```